# What is the Difference between Salat and other ibadah from another religion? Regarding find peace

Tags: salat, islamic-philosophy, other-religions, worship

My Question is Regarding find peace when you're praying,
If a Muslim offer shalah and find peace, is there any difference between shalah and ohter praying from another religion.

Hindu, Budha, Crhistian and other religion, they say : they are finding peace when they are praying.

i'm wondering is there any Difference peace in Islam when praying and peace in another religion?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that if finding peace is the purpose of Salah then there should not be any difference in the peace-finding rituals of other religions.

I believe you asked this question due to *Surely in Allah's remembrance do hearts find rest. [13:28]*. However, this is not the reason for which salah is ordained. Its reason is mentioned in *So serve Me and establish Prayers to remember Me [20:14]*.

If you read the Al-Fatiha (which we recite in every prayer) with this perspective you'll see that it beautifully serves the purpose. It reminds us that:

1. We are the servants of our compassionate ever-merciful Lord
2. The same Lord has put His servants in trial and He will be the Judge in the Day of Reckoning
3. Then we we pray Him to lead us to the right path so that we can succeed in this trial

Comment: in my opinion there must be someone who answer this question who is not Muslim before but when he/she finds the truth they convert to be a Muslim, so they can tell the difference. and Allah must give something difference in the heart of Muslim when praying shalat

Answer (score 1):

The real purpose of Salat is not to get only Peace. Yes it is true that offering Salat gives a person peace internally, but the main purpose of Salat is to obey the order of Almighty Allah. We have to offer Salat 5 times a day because it's the order of Almighty ALLAH. Moreover, Salat is the source of asking forgiveness form ALLAH and asking our desires and our needs from ALLAH. Hazrat Anas RadiAllahu Anhu said, which translates as "*`Whenever Prophet Muhammad Sallalu AlaihiWassallum confronts any severe problem, then he used to offer Namaz (Salat)`* 
Hence Salat is not only the source of Peace. It's the source of Jannah (Heaven). A translation of another hadith is: **`Salat is the key to Heaven`**